# Pick up directory folder dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I need to replace the hardcoded folder name with that set by specific docType Property Value, here's my partial view page code,

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

@{
    string folderPath = Server.MapPath("/media");
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath + "/1039");
}
@foreach (string item in files){
     <img src="/media/1039/@Path.GetFileName(item)" />
}
```

And I have tried the following but I think that it's missing something,

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    string folderPath = Server.MapPath("/media");
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath + "/@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("placeID")");
}
@foreach (string item in files){
    <img src="/media/@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("placeID")/@Path.GetFileName(item)" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by (@MrMarsRed) and here's the right code,
And his answer was as following,

You are not doing what you are expecting with this string:

```
"/@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("placeID")"
```

Since you are inside of a string in a C# code block, that @Model has no special meaning (i.e., it literally gets interpreted that way, rather than getting evaluated as an expression). You want something like this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath + "/" + Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("placeID"));
```

And here's the final code, which worked perfectly

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
    @{
        string folderPath = Server.MapPath("/media");
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath + "/" + Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("placeID"));
    }
    @foreach (string item in files){
        <img src="/media/@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("placeID")/@Path.GetFileName(item)" />
    }
```

Comment: It's fine if you want to answer your own question, but please provide an explanation of how this code solves the issue.

Comment: I have edited my answer and provided an explanation of how this code solves the issue, I hope that's good enough, thank you